# creating a textfile and cannot identify the location the created file goes

Tags: c#

What is wrong with this code? The text file is not created in the `bin\Debug` directory!

```
string path = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/" + "Contacts.txt";

if (!File.Exists(path))
{
    File.CreateText(path);
    MessageBox.Show("file created successfully");
}

using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("path", true))
{
    sw.WriteLine(txtCntname1.Text + "," + txtCntnum1.Text + "," + txtCntnum2.Text + "," + txtCntnum3.Text + ",");
    sw.Close();
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named [ask]. You might also want to learn about [example].

Comment: Do you have really put the variable _path_ between double quotes in the StreamWriter constructor?

Comment: Have you tried placing a breakpoint on the line following the `path` assignment to inspect the variable and see what the resulting path actually is?

Answer (score 1):

Aside from that `path` should probably not be in quotes here:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("path", true))
```

Do not use [`Environment.CurrentDirectory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.currentdirectory?view=netframework-4.8)! It does not always represent the directory you started your executable from, since it only represents your *working directory*.

Please use [`Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.location?view=netframework-4.8) to get the full path of the executing assembly and then extract only the directory from it, using:

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)
```

Alternatively you could also use [`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.basedirectory?view=netframework-4.8) for identifying the directory your application is residing in.

Of course not using an absolute path is a possibility as well, you can create your file using a relative path, by not specifying any directory:

```
File.CreateText("Contacts.txt")
```

**EDIT:**

Seeing how you formed your path, please also use [`Path.Combine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=netframework-4.8) to build your paths:

```
var appBaseDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
var contactsFilePath = Path.Combine(appBaseDir, "Contacts.txt");
```

Comment: @Jane if this solved your question, could you please mark it as the answer, so others know that this issue is solved?

Answer (score 1):

You have two ways of calculating EXE's directory:

#### 1) Implicit

You can use only the file name. In this case, the file will be created in the same folder with EXE file:

```
File.CreateText("Contacts.txt")
```

#### 2) Explicit

If you need reliable way to get the EXE's directory, then you need to use `AppDomain`:

```
string exe_dir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
```

Then, instead of manually concatenating strings to form a path, use [Path.Combine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine) method:

```
string file_path = Path.Combine(exe_dir, "Contact.txt");
```

The code (`Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location`), offered by @TobiasTengler, won't work, for instance, for Excel/Word add-in.